# Sqlite: column_id REFERENCES parent(id) VS foreign key (column_id) REFERENCES parent(id)

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I got some question with FOREIGN KEYS in SQLITE as there are 2 syntax options.

Assume, that we have parent table already

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id, some_text)
```

We can create child table with Foreign Keys using 2 ways:

1. CREATE TABLE child(id, some_child_data, parent_id REFERENCES parent(id))
2. CREATE TABLE child(id, some_child_data, parent_id, FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id))

**My questions are:**

1. Is there any difference in those 2 syntax?
2. Can I use ON UPDATE / ON DELETE modifications using any of those syntax options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly same thing. You can define a foreign key with column definition or at the end of the table creation. Result will be same.

But as @Mike T mentioned:

> A difference between the two is that you are limited to a single
> column foreign key when using the column definition, at the table
> definition level you can have composite foreign keys.

You can use on update/ on delete with in both the syntaxes.

DB-Fiddle:

Parent table:

```
 CREATE TABLE parent (id int , some_text varchar(50));
```

Chile table:

```
 CREATE TABLE child(id, some_child_data, parent_id REFERENCES parent(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

or

```
 CREATE TABLE child(id, some_child_data, parent_id, FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id))
```

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5f6c341ba4641322def97be130d404b3)*

Comment: A difference between the two is that you are limited to a single column foreign key when using the column definition, at the table definition level you can have composite foreign keys.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Revised my answer with your input. Thanks a lot.